# How to select element by class and get text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape addresses in this page: https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#news

How can I get values which under `class=sorting_1`? It is difficult for me. I'm completely new to `Beautifulsoup`.

[image: 1]

Comment: `soup.select_one(".sorting_1").text`

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? And instead of linking to an image of some text, can you copy that text in your question description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using find:

```py
[t.get_text(strip=True) for t in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'sorting_1'})]
```

or if you're sure that's the only class for the tags you want:

```py
[t.get_text(strip=True) for t in soup.find_all(class_='sorting_1')]
```

or using select

```py
[t.get_text(strip=True) for t in soup.select('.sorting_1')]
```

---

Any of the above should work; and if you're going to be working with BeautifulSoup, you should really familiarize yourself with [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and/or go through at least one [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-python-using-beautiful-soup/).